Hugo website not render recent posts and featured posts
I have problem about posts ( not updated ) with tags , featured, recents posts . Everything worked before after that i have this issue. There is no problem on local but when i deploy my website online the posts not updated as explained before
I noticed that this problem appeared when summer time was adjusted (i.e. from March 31)
I use version 0.120.3 of hugo
Please Help

Without code or error messages its not possible to answer your question.
